# form select helper not rendering html options

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form object and for some reason it doesn't render the class I have:

```
<%= f.select :assignee_id, User.all.collect {|us| [ us.name, us.id ] }, selected: current_user.id, class: "form-control" %>
```

When I inspect the html, that select tag does not have a class of "form-control".

In terms of acceptable arguments, I followed this link (Note in my case, since I used form_for, I don't need to specify object argument):

```
select(object, method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {}) public
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select

What may I be doing wrong?

Comment: <%= f.select :assignee_id,User.all.collect {|us| [ us.name, us.id ] }, {selected: current_user.id}, {class: "form-control"} %>

Comment: ahh! I see it was treating the last two as a single hash. I have to explicitly put the curly braces to indicate two hashes!